# Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR >> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, karma-jasmine

Getting an error loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks. All other tasks load fine.
Started to see the problem after updating a number of dependencies including grunt-karma and karma.

From my package.json:

"grunt-karma": "^3.0.2",
"karma": "^4.2.0",

My Karma config in Gruntfile.js:

```
/**
 * The Karma configurations.
 */
karma: {
    options: {
        configFile: '<%= build_dir %>/karma-unit.js'
    },
    unit: {
        port: 9019,
        background: true
    },
    continuous: {
        singleRun: true
    }
},
```

When I run grunt watch --verbose --debug this is the error I see:

```
Registering "grunt-karma" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt-karma\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt-karma\package.json...OK
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:117
>>   async start () {
>>         ^^^^^
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>>   at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
>>   at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>>   at Module.load (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\coffeescript\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
>>   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>>   at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\karma\lib\index.js:4:16)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>>   at Module.load (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\coffeescript\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
>>   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>>   at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt-karma\tasks\grunt-karma.js:9:30)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>>   at Module.load (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\coffeescript\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
>>   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>>   at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>>   at loadTask (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:313:10)
>>   at C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:351:7
>>   at Array.forEach (native)
>>   at loadTasks (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:350:11)
>>   at Task.task.loadNpmTasks (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:398:5)
>>   at Object.module.exports (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\Gruntfile.js:17:11)
>>   at loadTask (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:315:10)
>>   at Task.task.init (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:434:5)
>>   at Object.grunt.tasks (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt.js:111:8)
>>   at Object.module.exports [as cli] (C:\Development\gitrepository\ContactCenterRepos\ccs-sdk\CCS_SDK\JavaScript\RefClient\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\cli.js:27:9)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pruane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt:44:20)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>>   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>>   at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>>   at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
>>   at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>>   at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Comment: I was also see the following error: Warning: Task "karma:continuous" not found. Use --force to continue. Resolved this by removing 'karma:continuous' from my GruntFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted my karma version back to 3.1.4 and no longer see the issue:

```
"karma": "^3.1.4",
```

Also tried Karma version 4.0.0 but error was still present.